# Tabs are converted to column breaks... unless those tabs are copied from a web browser

Tags: html, browser, google-sheets, textarea, google-docs

Tabs are converted to column breaks when pasted into most spreadsheet programs... but not when those tabs are copied from a web browser. What's going on here?

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Copy some tab-delimited data ([example](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g2nttNd1)) from a browser into your clipboard
2. Open a Google Sheet
3. Click *once* on any cell
4. Paste the contents of your clipboard

**Expected result:**

The tabs are converted to column breaks. Pieces of text that were separated by tabs now reside in their own cells.

**Actual results:**

The tabs are not converted to column breaks. All text is pasted into one cell.

**However...** and this is where things get weird... if the tab-delimited data is first copied into a textarea ([example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chgc9kfp/show/)), and then that same tab-delimited data is copied from the textarea into a Google Sheet, the tabs are converted to column breaks as expected.

---

Very strange indeed. Can anyone offer insight into why this happens?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insight, yes. An explanation of why this feature has been broken for years, even with the "New Sheets"? Sorry, no.

The tab-delimited text from the pastebin example appears in the Windows clipboard like this, in "49407: HTML Format":

[image: screenshot]

Contrast this with the text copied from a textarea (or a text editor; I tried the same with wordpad), which is plain "1: CF_TEXT" format:

[image: screenshot]

Since there is no option to "paste as plain text" into Sheets, the HTML version of the clipboard is used (when there is one). That's nice if the HTML includes formatting that might be retained - but isn't so handy in this case.